# Upgrade vmware tools issue

Tags: linux, redhat, vmware-vsphere

I try to upgrade vmware tools on a VM (Red hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.1) the package I try to install is VMwareTools-8.6.10-913593.tar.gz.

In a step of installation I get this error :

> No X install found.
>
> Creating a new initrd boot image for the kernel.
>    ERROR: "/sbin/dracut --force --add-drivers "vmxnet3 vmw_pvscsi vmxnet"
>    /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64.img >/dev/null 2>&1" exited with
>    non-zero status.
>
> Your system currently may not have a functioning init image and may not boot
>    properly.  DO NOT REBOOT!  Please ensure that you have enough free space
>    available in your /boot directory and run this configuration script again.
>
> Execution aborted.

Comment: How much disk space do you have?

Comment: sda is about 20G

Comment: How much free space do you have in your `/boot` partition?

Comment: Found it, /boot was mounted on RO

Comment: To avoid this question floating around forever, do you want to write that up as an answer, then accept it when the site permits you to do so (which may take 24-48 hours)?

Comment: I'm sorry. Why was your /boot partition read-only in the first place?

Comment: @ewwhite I don't really know, it is a strategy of the campagny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, /boot was mounted on RO